# how do i get a variable out of powershell in jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

```
        steps {
            script{
                env.StorysTested = ''

                try{
                    powershell('''
                     //some code here
                     foreach ( $item in $Comments ) 
                     {  
                     //some code here
                     //assigning a new value to StoryTested env variable
                     $env:StorysTested = "some value"   
                     }
                     //below line works fine and displays the value
                     Write-Output "Stories tested : $env:StorysTested"
                     ''')
                     //below null value is displayed for StorysTested`` 
                     echo " From Grrovy : ${env.StorysTested}"
                    }
                    catch(err)
                    {
                     throw err
                    }
           }
```

I am using a jenkins declarative pipeline.
In the above code i m trying to use the value of $env:StorysTested in groovy which was assigned in powershell. Is there any way i can retain a variable value that was assigned in powershell, after the powershell execution is over. storing it in env variable was one way i thought of but clearly that didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

If you set an environment variable using `$env:StorysTested = "some value"`, this variable is stored for the **powershell process** and is not permanent or visible outside this process.

To create more permanent environment variables (i.e., user-level or machine-level) you need to use the .NET Framework and the `SetEnvironmentVariable` method:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("StorysTested", "some value", "User")
```

or

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("StorysTested", "some value", "Machine")
```

---

To delete from within PowerShell, you use the same .NET method and assign a `$null` value to the variable like this:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("StorysTested",$null,"User")  # or "Machine" of course
```

Hope that helps